# Is it okay to say "I wrote this article after reading many data"?

Tags: word-choice, singular-vs-plural, controversial

What I want to say is that I write an analysis article about global population growth, and I worked on that with some public data. But I want to emphasis that I read a lot of data. Can I use "many" here?

Thanks!

Comment: Something like "During the course of my research I obtained and analysed a large volume of publicly available data" Stick well away from 'many' with data unless your reader has expressed a preference - http://grammarist.com/usage/data/

Comment: This answer to another question might be helpful also: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24032/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer has to be a little complicated, because in the English-speaking world, there is a long-running controversy about whether **data** can be singular, and you should know about this controversy.

---

Some people say that **data** can only be plural; its singular is **datum**. Their reasoning is that **data**, like many technical terms in English, is borrowed from [Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/), and the usual custom in English is to retain the [Latin plural](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/51029/6700) for technical terminology. By this reasoning, you should follow grammar like this:

> One **datum** is insignificant. You can only get a statistically significant result if you collect **many data**.

However, over the last hundred years or so, many people have found it useful to treat **data** as a singular mass noun. The singular leads the reader to imagine data the way we think of other mass nouns: as something like sand or water, not as something that we count, like cars or houses. By about 1980, singular **data** became fully accepted in most formal writing. One reason for the change in grammar is that people seldom need to talk about a single **datum**, and **datum** became a rare word. Instead, when people need the singular, they follow grammar like this:

> One **data point**, or one **piece of data**, is insignificant. You must collect **much more data** than that to get a statistically significant result.

As the word **data** became more common, people invented new meanings for **datum**, though only for use in very specialized, technical fields, like [geodesy](https://books.google.com/books?id=LmXMBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=north%20american%20datum&pg=PA50#v=onepage&q=north%20american%20datum&f=false). When people need to make a plural for **datum** in these new senses of the word, it would be confusing to say **data**, so they say **datums**.

Today, the expectation that **data** is singular is reinforced by new phrases that exploit the singular number, like **data type** and **data warehouse**, where **data** is used as an attributive noun in a way that's customary only when the noun is singular. The common word **database** also leads people to expect that **data** is singular.

---

So, with one caveat, I recommend that you *not* say **many** data. **Many data** would require your reader to think of **data** as plural. For most English speakers today, using **data** as a plural is a little jarring—unless you are working in one of the rare fields where **datum** is still used as the singular of **data**. A helpful rule of thumb is: If you or your audience would say **data point** or **one piece of data** instead of **datum**, then you should treat **data** as singular.

These are good:

> I analyzed **a lot of** data. *[This is grammatical whether **data** is singular or plural.]*
>
> **Much** of the data **suggests** that global population growth is slowing, but a small **part** of the data raises doubts.
>
> I wrote this article after examining **a great deal of** data.

In the last sentence, you could substitute **a great amount of data**, **a large volume of data**, or other common expressions that go with singular mass nouns. All of these phrases emphasize that you read a lot of data. Also, the verb **examine** makes that point more clearly than **read**. Usually we say that computers **read** data; human beings **examine**, **consider**, and **analyze** data. (Computers are also said to **analyze** data, but mechanically rather than thoughtfully.)

Some sources for data, such as public databases, are count nouns and should be plural:

> I examined **many** public **databases**.

Here is the one caveat: *Some* people, a minority today, are sticklers for the older usage. Often these people work in positions of authority in organizations that uphold traditions, like schools and governments. In countries where English is not the native language, older forms are often taught, and correct modern usage is sometimes marked wrong on exams. So, *know your audience.* If your audience wants plural **data**, give them plural **data**. If you don't have specific information that your audience insists on the older grammar, then use singular **data** and avoid **many**.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice: once for the _data as a mass noun_ part, and once for the _computers read data, people analyze it_ part. Both are great points.

Comment: "I recommend that you not say". I liked your reply, but I can't stop asking myself whether that "strange" construction (with "not" instead of "don't) could be correct. Could you clarify if that expression was intentional?

Comment: @lnjuanj It was intentional, for two reasons: (1) That's the ordinary way to negate the subjunctive mood in AmE. If you're from England, it might seem unfamiliar. Search for "[recommend that you not](https://www.google.com/?#q=%22recommend+that+you+not%22)" for many examples and some articles discussing the transatlantic difference. (2) I'm guessing that this construction is a little easier for non-natives to understand, since it lacks "do". I thought the simple negation of the subjunctive might help the main point stand out a little better amidst the caveat and discussion of changing usage.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I'm not English, just learning :) I mostly read in English and hadn't ever seen that construction. Your first reason has helped me discover something new: Thanks a lot! About the second reason... I'm Spanish and we use subjunctives a lot, but they teach British English here, so I guess that's why I feel more comfortable with the "don't" construction. Otherwise, Spanish people would be happier using those subjunctives in English too ;)

Comment: @lnjuanj Well, come to America and enjoy our subjunctive mood! :) Also, you might find [this tag](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjunctive) interesting.

Answer (score 1):

"Many" doesn't work here because it's describing a singular noun. "Data" can't be "many" because it's just one thing.

If you said "I wrote this article after reading many books" it would be appropriate, because "books" is plural and when there are multiples of something, you can have many of them.

"I wrote this article after reading a lot of data" is a simple way of saying what you're intending to.

Comment: Actually, "data" is the plural of "datum". Not so long ago, people fought about whether "data" could be extended to serve as a singular mass noun. That usage is now commonly accepted even in formal writing, but plural "data" is still established, grammatical English. Google "many data" and you'll see lots of articles about this. [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=xUy-NNnSQIIC&lpg=PA995&dq=%22many%20data%22&pg=PA995#v=onepage&q=%22many%20data%22&f=false) is typical contemporary usage of plural "data".

Comment: "A lot of..." applies to plural nouns and uncountable things like water and red. So using the same example as in the answer, you can say "a lot of books", but not "a lot of book". That's why you can say "a lot of data" but not "a lot of datum".

Comment: @BenKovitz - Sorry, but it doesn't work in this case. "I read a datum" would use the singular form of data, but it simply wouldn't make much sense. One might say "I read a single datum from the list", but the unmodified datum use would sound very odd.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Indeed people don't usually say "datum" anymore. But if you use "data" in the plural, that's the corresponding singular. I _have_ encountered this in real literature and speech, and said it myself, but only in very technical settings. "The reader reads the next datum…"; [examples](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q="read+the+next+datum"). After reading the answers and comments so far, I'm now thinking that a good rule of thumb might be, "If you don't know what a datum is, you don't know what plural data is—and so you shouldn't use either word."

Comment: pixiesquisher, are you a native speaker of English? If so, can you tell me where you're from and roughly how old you are? Your answer might be informative as an illustration of different understanding of the grammatical number of **data** among different fluent speakers. If you're not a native speaker, can you shed some light on how you came to understand data as "just one thing"?

Comment: I am a native speaker, I'm from California, and I'm in my late twenties. I tend to err on the side of common vernacular over what could be debated as technically correct where non-native speakers (such as OP) are concerned. Very, very few would say "many data" today, and if they did (they could, because in a technical sense it's correct!) it would give most readers pause.

Comment: So you knew that **data** can also be plural (even though that usage is rapidly fading)?

Comment: Oh, no, I had no idea "datum" was a thing. My remarks on the technicality of "many data"'s correctness was based only in other peoples' comments. Deciding to err on common vernacular over technical correctness is also based upon the comments here -- just me supporting my answer, I suppose!

Answer (score 1):

> I wrote this article after reading many data

A *datum* is a unit of collected information.  Here you are saying you have read many sets of collected information - in the sense of taking readings from an instrument, going through a process to sample and read the state of something, etc.

> But I want to emphasis that I read a lot of data

Right here, you are expressing it in the way many would expect to hear it.  *I read a lot of data* means you read a lot of articles or lists of data.

One problem is that *reading data* implies you are looking at lists of numbers, but doing nothing further.  So even this:

> I wrote this article after reading a lot of data

can come off as somewhat "incomplete" because you really should do more with data than just read it.  This is probably better:

> I wrote this article after *analyzing* a lot of data

Answer (score 0):

As @BenKovits commented, data is originally a plural form of *datum*.

The word "data" is defined as a mass noun in [Oxford Online Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/data) and it would be better to use "much" than "many" based on this definition. The linked Ngram Viewer, [collected much data vs collected many data](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=collected+much+data%2C+collected+many+data&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccollected%20much%20data%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccollected%20many%20data%3B%2Cc0), seems to favor "much data" over "many data", but there is no much difference. It would not be incorrect to use "many data". It will depend on how you perceive the word.

As @PerryW commented, using "a large amount of data" or "a large volume of data" would be a good alternative.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/data) confirms that the word *data* could be used as a singular or plural noun in construction. The word *datum* is not broaldy used in contemporary English.

Comment: -1 `it would not be incorrect to use "many data"` I must disagree.   I have never heard or read "many data", and "correct" is what people say, not what they "can say" according to some abstract rule.   Even "these data" is rare compared to "this data".  The plural is perceived as pedantry, even by the well-educated.

Comment: @TRomano Are you saying that [the sentence in the book](https://books.google.com/books?id=YADecaAmD7EC&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq="collected+many+data"&source=bl&ots=ZWFPe-Z4Af&sig=ad--UdzX2eRfDTXSmsnzkgRkIUs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiojbHtjP3MAhVDF6YKHZS_BZcQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=%22collected%20many%20data%22&f=false) written by two British scholars is incorrect? It might not be more broadly used than "collected much data", but I don't see the problem with the sentence. Do you? I deleted the first Ngram as "many data" are used as an attributive phrase in some cases.

Comment: I'm saying that "many data" is a pedanticism.  I can find only a handful of times when it is used.

Comment: @TRomano How can you explain this Ngram Viewer? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=these+data%2Cthis+data&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthese%20data%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthis%20data%3B%2Cc0. I don't understand why it has to be something wrong just because you have never heard or read it.https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=these+data+are%2C+this+data+is&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthese%20data%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthis%20data%20is%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I would explain that as the likely result of editorial intervention. One rarely *hears* "*these* data" in natural conversation. One *hears* "this data shows" far more often than "these data show" even by speakers who would write "these data show". In formal contexts, they will treat "data" as plural because they know it's "correct" to do so, but in informal contexts they will often do as the average speaker does.

Comment: @TRomano I said, " It would not be incorrect to use "many data."" and  "it would be better to use "much" than "many" based on this definition." What do you think is wrong with my statements? Don't you agree that we need to show learners as many cases as possible so that they can understand what they are? They will know what you are talking about now when their English is improved. I don't think my answer is wrong

Comment: @TRomano We might read different books or we might be different ages, but I have encountered "many data" in real life, even in speech. It's been declining in usage, but it has a long-standing pedigree and is found in many books that are still read. See, for example, [this Ngram](http://bit.ly/1Ukufgs). That said, I share your disgust with "many data" and also find it pedantic. If you'd like to pass a harsh law against its use by anyone who doesn't know the singular, I'm in.

Comment: Would either of you care to explain https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=much+data+are&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmuch%20data%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmuch%20data%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMuch%20data%20are%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments, but I'm still confused. I read your comments . So I guess the conclusion is `many` is ok but `much` is more recently used? Thanks again!

Comment: @TRomano That's interesting! One possible explanation is that there are [very few hits](http://bit.ly/27XpiBZ). But I think a more likely explanation is that the momentum to treat "data" as singular started _long_ ago, because even when it was clearly plural, there were many fewer occasions to say "datum". Compare [this](http://bit.ly/1TNvh4W) and [this](http://bit.ly/1TNvh4W). I don't think we disagree about the phony and pedantic sound that "many data" usually has today. But I do think that plural "data" has legitimate, non-pretentious currency in some (unusual) settings.

Comment: @TRomano [Here's](http://bit.ly/24emThs) an example. You might object that the author is not fluent in English. The point, though, is that he is using plural _data_ to communicate something real, as we normally use plurals, not putting on airs. BTW, in most settings where _datum_ is common today, people don't use it as the singular of _data._ They use it for new meanings, which they pluralize as _datums._ I find this kind of observation much more helpful than the usual frequency-of-use arguments. Singular _data_ and plural _datums_ are useful for _communicating,_ not just flock-following.

Comment: @TRomano Would you care to explain https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=too+much+data%2C+too+many+data&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ctoo%20much%20data%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btoo%20much%20data%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BToo%20much%20data%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BToo%20Much%20Data%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTOO%20MUCH%20DATA%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ctoo%20many%20data%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btoo%20many%20data%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BToo%20many%20data%3B%2Cc0 ? It shows "too much data" got much traction after 1950 or 1960, but doesn't show us "too many data" is not being used.

Comment: @TRomano and Rathony: OK, you guys talked me into it. I posted an answer. Ngram [away](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/91005/6700)…